# Word Bookmarks in vbscript not working in Office 2016

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I have a vbscript which inserts some values on a word document using bookmarks. It worked fine until last week when we changed office 2013 with office 2016. Now I get an general error 
[image: Error image]

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\scripts\word\bookmarkdoc.docx")

Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("nei1").Range
objRange.Text = "5.40"
```

Comment: Can you try writing "Dim objRange As Object" and check what happens? I suppose you have dimensionised it as range.

Comment: This code was working on word 2013. Word 2016 is not working.

Comment: So did you try it? I was having similar problem some time ago with Word VBA (even asked a question in SO) and I recall that it has fixed it somehow.

Comment: Still is giving the error. When i remove bookmarks it works.

Comment: The "obvious" question is: does this bookmark exist? And have you spelled it correctly - is that last character truly the number one (1) or should it be a small-case "L"? Can you check whether the following returns True, False or perhaps also an error: `objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("nei1")` Another thing to check is whether you get a better result using: `objDoc.Bookmarks.Item("nei1").Range`

Comment: Yes bookmark exists. Same script runs on word 2013 in pc which have word 2013. It doesnt work in word 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full script? check if there is some error handling routine, as it looks like this messagebox is a custom one.

The code itself seems to have no errors. But you can give it a try without createobject:

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objRange As Word.Range

Set objWord = New Word.Application

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("c:\scripts\word\bookmarkdoc.docx")

Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("neil1").Range

objRange.Text = "5.40"
```

Comment: This part of the script is generating error. I tested it by putting messages line after line. Error is in creating Bookmark: Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("neil1").Range.

In word 2013 it worked fine. So there is a problem with upgrade, something changed.

Comment: sadly I can't really check this as I'm forced to use Office 2010